# Remotely directing actors and recording sound

Tags: audio, remote-access, audio-recording

I am directing actors to produce an audio show, on which I later add video. In a time of pandemic, I prefer to direct and record remotely. I know that some podcast producers (such as Radio Ambulante by NPR) worked completely remotely even before the pandemic. I would like to use software to interact with and direct actors and record the audio takes. Ideally, I could also produce the sound but I can also do that in Audacity or Final Cut Pro.

What are good software solutions to remotely direct actors and record sound?

**Update**: The solution should be cross-platform, as I have macOS and others have Windows. It would be a bonus if it can be browser-only on the actor's side. The cost should be less than $30 for one hour of content, ideally with a free trial.